# How to render HTML Template and bind data from JSON response in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have to render an HTML template using reactjs. HTML template is dynamic and get through an API call. There is provision in template to bind the data in html.
Sample HTML template is as follows,

```
<a target="_blank" href="{ad.url}">
    <div class="ads temp-1">
        <h2>{ad.name}</h2>
        <div class="adv-content">
            <div class="advs-image">
                <img src="{ad.image}" />
            </div>
            <div class="adv-desc">{ad.description}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Here `ad` is an Object which contains the properties `url`, `image`, `name`, `description` etc

Sample `ad` Object is as follows,

```
var ad = {
    "image": "testimage.jpg",
    "url": "http: //google.com",
    "name": "testadvertisement",
    "description": "testdescription"
}
```

I have achieved this in AngularJs using, `$compile` service.

Now I want to move this to reactjs. 
I have tried to render using reactjs `render` function, But it didn't help. It renders html as string.

Is there any compile like function in reactjs ? Or could you please suggest any other way to do this right way ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not already including such templates as .jsx?

Comment: It should be dynamic. Templates should able to add from admin dashboard. That is why it provided through API

Comment: Then I would either make a `POST` to `/api/render/:templateName` with provided data and expect plain HTML back, or use Handlebars / lodash microtemplating, or even [something like this](https://github.com/jamesmartin/react-remote-component-demo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I correctly undestand you should use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop.

For example:

```
// SomeComponent.js

// other methods...

render() {
  // `htmlFromResponse` is your plain html string from response.
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlFromResponse }} />
  );
}
```

Using this prop, you can render plain html string into `div` element.

---

If you are getting html template from server, and want to pass variable to it before rendering, you can do it with `Mustache` package:

```
import Mustache from 'mustache';

// template should contain variables in {{ ... }}
const html = Mustache.render(htmlFromServer, {
  variable: 'value'
});
```

Next, you can render output `html` using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop.

Comment: Thanks. It will render HTML inside the div. Is there any way to bind the variable in template using { } or {{ }} ?

Comment: @MohammedSafeer, check updated answer, I explained how to render template from server.

Answer (score 0):

create a react component which renders the HTML data, then pass your Json data as Prop to the component. this will give React element access to data and Rendered HTML will be automatically updated when Json data changes.

Check out some react tutorial video over youtube, that will give you an overview of how ReactJs works

here is how to Pass Props

https://jsfiddle.net/abhirathore2006/6a403kap/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  console.log(this.props)
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}
    <h5>{this.props.d1.name}</h5>
    id:{this.props.d1.id}
    </div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" d1={{"name":"test","id":"5"}} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```